# TcpListener invalid argument specified

Tags: c#, tcplistener

[image: code problem]

I'm not really sure what is wrong because I have tried the other method overload for TcpListener.Start(int backlog) but the same result occurred. Maybe it is something wrong with how I initialized it?

Comment: you should show the whole exception stack trace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you specifying a host and port twice? Supplying them to the `TcpListener` constructor should suffice:

```
public Station()
{
    this.connections = new List<TcpClient>();
    this.server = new TcpCient(IPAddress.Loopback, 6969);
}

public void Start()
{
    server.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I feel really dumb/didn't notice that. Thanks!